# is there a way where I can write my RDF data DIRECTLY and query it via SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, fuseki

I'm practicing some SPARQL queries and features, my problem is that whenever I get new RDF data, I go to protoge, build classes and relationships and instances that accompany to these RDF, then explore these data, then import it to a dataset in Fuseki, then I query it. 
and if I make any mistake in my data, I'd need to repeat the whole process.

It's becoming tedious and time consuming, that's why I badly need to ask you if there's a place (tool or a fuseki support plugin ... or anything ..) where I can write my simple rdf data directly and then query it from my fuseki.

that data I want to write for example is really simple, it's like this:

```
@prefix dei: <http://www.warsaw.pl/ > .     
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .      
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .     
dei:~rcardish/     
      rdf:type foaf:Person ;     
      foaf:name “Rafa Cardish" ;     
 foaf:member <http://www.warsaw.pl> ;     
      rdfs:SeeAlso <http://www.linkedin.com/in/rafacardish>
```

but even that simple and small rdf takes me time in my current way.

Your help is appreciated.

#### Update 1

Now I can do this to load my data into fuseki

> ./fuseki-server --file=/Users/bla bla bla/rdfData.rdf /testdataset

and this is the data

```
@prefix dc:   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix :     <http://example.org/book/> .
@prefix ns:   <http://example.org/ns#> .

:book1  dc:title     "SPARQL Tutorial" .
:book1  ns:price     42 .
:book1  ns:discount  0.2 .

:book2  dc:title     "The Semantic Web" .
:book2  ns:price     23 .
:book2  ns:discount  0.25 .
```

but I don't know how to query it because when i run Fuseki, i go to query and I have to select a dataset but here there is no dataset shown in the drop down

#### Update 2

Now it's working, my mistake is that the file extension was .ttl.rdf, when I make it .ttl alone it works

Comment: You get RDF from an external source? Why is there Protege in-between? And have you tried [using Fuseki to serve RDF data files](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/#running-a-fuseki-server)?

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz I'm using protege in order to generate the correct rdf. for exmaple i'm practicing the sparql queries from this link https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#BasicGraphPatterns but how can i write the data to fuseki in order to query it?

Comment: Did you open the link I gave you? :). You don't have to write to Fuseki. Simplest way would be to have Fuseki serve data from your RDF file: `fuseki-server --file=FILE /DatasetPathName`

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz do you mean to save my rdf in a file and run that command? if yes, then how can I query it? again I go to fuseki sparql end point? if yes, what is the dataset? because in fuseki i need to select the dataset and it is from a dropdown list

Comment: Yes, save and start server. I'm no Fuseki expert. You would have to experiment and see for yourself.

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz the fuseki-server is an exe and I'm working on mac, do you know any equivelent for mac please ?

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz now I can run it, but I'm getting this error `Can't guess language for file` I just copied past the pdf, should I make an extension for the file? if yes, what please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103109/discussion-between-ania-david-and-tomasz-pluskiewicz).

Comment: @AniaDavid If someone hasn't posted a comment or answer on a question, they don't get notified when you use the "@" notation.  So I didn't get any notification about your first comment.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Oh okay i didn't know thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line tools (e.g. [Redland tools](http://librdf.org/rasqal/)) or write a simple script to load RDF and run SPARQL queries over it (e.g. [using RDFlib](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html)):

1) Using Redland: `roqet query.rq -D data.ttl -r json`

Runnit it with a query for `?s dc:title ?title` using your example data returns:

```
"bindings" : [
  {
    "s" : { "type": "uri", "value": "http://example.org/book/book1" },
    "title" : { "type": "literal", "value": "SPARQL Tutorial" }
  },
  {
    "s" : { "type": "uri", "value": "http://example.org/book/book2" },
    "title" : { "type": "literal", "value": "The Semantic Web" }
  }
]
```

JSON is one of result formats but you can also get CSV, etc.

See also: [Command line Semantic Web with Redland](https://www.dajobe.org/talks/201003-semweb-sxsw/)

2) [Using RDFlib to run SPARQL queries](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html) is also quite a compact way to do this (in Python):

```
import rdflib

g = rdflib.Graph()

g.parse("data.ttl", format="n3")

qres = g.query(
    """SELECT DISTINCT *
       WHERE {
          ?s dc:title ?title .
       }""")

for row in qres:
    print("%s : %s" % row)
```

Results:

```
http://example.org/book/book1 : SPARQL Tutorial
http://example.org/book/book2 : The Semantic Web
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jena's command line tools to run SPARQL queries easily.  In the Jena distribution, there's a **sparql** executable with **--query** and **--data** flags.  Once you have your RDF file (if you're writing by hand, I'd suggest using the Turtle/N3 serialization and giving your file the .ttl or .n3 suffix), and then it's easy to run a query.  For instance, when I have a **data.n3** file like this:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/a/35854800/1281433/>

<http://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/> :hasUserName "Joshua Taylor" .
```

and a **query.rq** like this:

```sql
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/a/35854800/1281433/>

select ?user where {
  ?user :hasUserName "Joshua Taylor"
}
```

Then I can get output like this:

```
$ sparql --query query.rq --data data.n3
```

```
---------------------------------------------
| user                                      |
=============================================
| <http://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/> |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am trying to check, kindly you said jena distribution, i went to this page https://jena.apache.org/download/ and download the distrubution but there is no sparql executable there. Anyway, now i already managed to work with jena but from the web browser, however this appraoch i like to try also

Comment: The sparql (and other) command line tool should be in the `/bin` (or /bat on Windows?) directory in your Jena installation.

Comment: Maybe Dockerfile will be helpful: https://gist.github.com/gwpl/cb10cf050ffaad08c9f3ba33d5ce745a